# How to override pre_validate and post_validate in wtforms?

Tags: python, validation, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to create a form with WTForms where a field is a SelectField with a special (custom) validation that (for example) checks something else if the current value is not valid (i.e. it is not an instance of the defined options).

I read in [the documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#basic-fields) that the right way to do it is to override the functions `pre_validate` or `post_validate` according with the needs.

So my approach is the following:

1 - I create a new field called MySelectForm:

```
class MySelectField(SelectField):
    def post_validate(self, form, validation_stopped):
        """overrides post validation"""
        #Here is my custom validation
```

2- I use this field instead of the original one in my form

What I cannot understand is: if, like I read in the docs, `post_validate` takes in input "The form the field belongs to", how do I access the current value of the field that is an instance of `MySelectField`?

In other words, can someone make an example of how to override `pre_validate` or `post_validate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `self` to the method and so you have your field object available. It inherits from WTForms' `Field` class and so you should have  `field.data` available. This contains the ["resulting (sanitized) value of calling either of the process methods."](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.4/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.data)

Comment: He asked for an example.

Answer (score 0):

below is part of source code

```py
# wtforms.fields.core.py  |  version: Flask-WTF 0.14.3

class Field(object):
    errors = tuple()
    ...

    def validate(self, form, extra_validators=tuple()):
        self.errors = list(self.process_errors)
        stop_validation = False

        self.check_validators(extra_validators)

        try:
            self.pre_validate(form)   # <---------- focus here
        except StopValidation as e:
            if e.args and e.args[0]:
                self.errors.append(e.args[0])
            stop_validation = True
        except ValueError as e:
            self.errors.append(e.args[0])

        # Run validators
        if not stop_validation:
            chain = itertools.chain(self.validators, extra_validators)
            stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)  # <-- It will run ``InputRequired, YourValidators1, YourValidators2, validate_username``  (see the example code)

        # Call post_validate
        try:
            self.post_validate(form, stop_validation)  # <---------- focus here
        except ValueError as e:
            self.errors.append(e.args[0])

        return len(self.errors) == 0
```

and I give you an example of `post_validate` (the `pre_validate` is very similar, and I believe you can do it by yourself)

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm, Form
from wtforms import StringField, ValidationError, StopValidation
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from typing import List


class StateStringField(StringField):
    ok_msg_list: List = None  # Because class ``wtforms.fields.core.Field`` are not existed any attributes I like, so I create one.

    def post_validate(self, form: Form, stop_validation: bool):
        if self.ok_msg_list is None:
            self.ok_msg_list = []
        if stop_validation:
            return
        if not 'errors':  # assume no errors...
            raise ValueError('...')
        else:
            self.ok_msg_list.append('OK')


class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StateStringField('User',
                                validators=[InputRequired(),
                                            # YourValidators2, YourValidators3
                                            ])

    def validate_username(self, field: StringField):
        if len(field.data) > 50:
            raise StopValidation('Name must be less than 50 characters')
```

```html
<!-- templates/auth/register.html-->
<form method="post">   
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>{{ form.username.label }} {{ form.username()|safe }}
      {% if form.username.errors %}
        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
          <p style="color:red;">{{ error }}<p>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if form.username['ok_msg_list'] %}  <!-- similar as python: if hasattr('ok_msg_list') -->
        {% for ok_msg in form.username.ok_msg_list %}
          <span style="color:blue;">{{ ok_msg|safe }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </p>
</form>
```

## Summary

You can use `post_validate` when you want to perform another validation after **all** the validations have been performed. (Personally, I think `post_validate` is similar to `finally`.

In my example, when the user verifies that **all** the validation is correct, an OK message appears next to it.

[image]